# Unable to start filebeat.error missing fileld

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

Below is my filebeat.yml file , I am unable to start service getting error

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
** paths:**
** - /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/logs/*.log**

document_type: apache-access
fields_under_root: true

output.logstash:
** hosts: '${host}'**
```

**host is environment variable i did export host="10.2.3.1:5044"**

```
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 filebeat[401]: Exiting: error initializing publisher: missing field accessing 'output.logstash.hosts' (source:'/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml')
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: filebeat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: Unit filebeat.service entered failed state.
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: filebeat.service failed.
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: filebeat.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for filebeat.service
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: Failed to start filebeat.
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: Unit filebeat.service entered failed state.
Apr 10 06:59:35 node1 systemd[1]: filebeat.service failed.``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, That's the issue is  Systemd does not pass environment variables. I started filebeat as `./filebeat -e -c filebeat.yml`   it worked for me

Comment: I think you should accept your solution to mark the question as solved and others can see the right answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this I see multiple syntax differences to your configuration. There are some examples at the bottom of the page even for hosts.

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.2/using-environ-vars.html
```

Hope it helps.